# Javascript not running nearlyfreespeech

Tags: javascript, html, onload, appendchild, nearlyfreespeech

I set up an e-commerce website for a friend using **javascript and html**, and with the **nearlyfreespeech** hosting service. I have made sure to load the html page correctly, and there are **no errors** (in both the console and on the actual page). I have also tried with both the javascript embedded in the html, and with 2 seperate files, but neither works. I am using **no external libraries** either. I added alerts for when the page loads, but nothing showed up. The page constructor is hooked up to the page via the **onload** event set on the body tag. I have tried it with **Firefox, Google Chrome, and  Internet Explorer**, but neither worked. When I moved the creation of the controls into the html, the controls were there (meaning that **the html is working**), but the alerts still didn't show (signifying that the javascript is either being omitted or that the onload event is not being fired). Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
  <title>GetLost</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadcontrols()
    {
        var items = ["Green cuff", "Red cuff"];
        var prices = ["20.00", "30.00"];
        var colors = ["Green", "Red"];
        var urls = ["http://media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/0f/f8/11/0ff811addad9b0165263eb73ba9806f0.jpg", "http://www.opalona.com/images/produits/big/big_2049-3.jpg"];
        var controls = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
        {
            var item = new loaditem(items[i], prices[i], colors[i], urls[i]);
            controls.concat(item);
        }
        alert("All items loaded.")
    }
    function loaditem(name, value, color, imageUrl)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
        this.color = color;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        var container = document.CreateElement("div");
        container.style.height = "300px";
        container.style.width = "200px";
        container.style.backgroundColor = color;
        scroller.appendChild(container);
        var image = document.CreateElement("img");
        image.style.height = "220px";
        image.style.witdh = "180px";
        image.setAttribute("src", imageUrl);
        container.appendChild(image);
        var name = document.CreateElement("h4");
        name.innerHTML = name + " for $" + value;
        container.appendChild(name);
        alert("The product " + name + "has been loaded.")
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="loadcontrols">
    <h1><b>Choose a product, and click on it to open it.</b></h1>
    <div style="overflow-x: scroll" name="scroller" height="310px" width="650px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onload` doesn’t take a function name; it takes some JavaScript code to run. If you had a single line of JavaScript code just referencing a variable:

```
loadcontrols
```

Then, well, nothing happens. If you want to call it, you need parentheses:

```
loadcontrols()
```